# Jenkins OpenLDAP authentication not working

Tags: ubuntu, authentication, jenkins, openldap

I am trying to get Jenkins to authenticate against a local OpenLDAP service, I can't seem to get users authenticated, even though I can successfully authenticate any user as the manager DN.

I have follow this deprecated tutorial: [DigitalOcean LDAP tutorial](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-and-configure-a-basic-ldap-server-on-an-ubuntu-12-04-vps).
Although this is meant for Ubuntu 12.04 which is deprecated, it seems to still be allright for the biggest part.

What am I missing here?

[image: Jenkins LDAP configuration]
[image: Jenkins failed authentication]
[image: OpenLDAP tree]

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I changed `user search filter` to `mail{0}` instead of `uid{0}`. Then use email address to test connection, which works.

[image]

[image]